# On a desktop browser, is there any way to navigate directly from the RPG.SE mainsite questions page to the Meta questions page?

Tags: support, user-interface

This question might be a *super* dumb -- or if it isn't, I have to imagine I'm not the first person to raise it. But I can't find anything about via searching (perhaps because it's tough to come up with an effective string). So.

I tried to read Meta regularly. Recent Meta activity has had me bouncing back and forth between Meta and mainsite with extra frequency. In the several years I've been on RPG.SE, however, I haven't found any *simple*, click-and-you're-there way to navigate from the mainsite homepage ("Top Questions") to the Meta homepage in the desktop browser UI. The only way I've found to do it is:

1. On mainsite, click the section/link for my user profile:

[image: partial screenshot of mainsite user interface with highlight on the user profile section]

2. Click the "Profiles" button in the upper-right to get to a drop-down menu, and click "Meta user":

[image: partial screenshot of mainsite user interface with "profiles" drop-down menu showing a red arrow pointing to the Meta user link]

3. Now that I'm on Meta user profile page, I can click the "Questions" link at the left:

[image: partial screenshot of Meta user profile page with a red arrow pointing to the "Questions" link]

Is it just me, or does this seem like a weird set of steps for what ought to be a very direct path between the two most important pieces of mainsite and Meta? Why must I go through my *profile* page to get to Meta *questions*? Or maybe there's some obvious one-click link somewhere that my eyeballs are simply refusing to see?

(Yeah, I know, we're talking about four clicks as opposed to one. And yeah, I know, I can just bookmark the Meta questions page; indeed I have done. I'm trying to understand the intent behind this architecture.)

Comment: Top right little Three lined chat blurb --> Current Community --> Roleplaying Games Meta

Comment: OK, so the verdict is "super dumb."

Comment: @screamline: It's easily missed! The site definitely needs to make it easier to navigate between mainsites, meta sites, and chat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There's a button in the burger menu

When you click the stack-icon/burger menu in the very right of the topbar, the dropdown includes a link to the meta site for the site you're currently on. It also has a link to the help pages and to chat, and below that will be other sites you have a profile on, and a menu for searching among the remaining stacks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: This answer could definitely use some further descriptive text, because it's currently completely inaccessible to someone using a screen reader (and still somewhat unclear even to those not using one...).